# How to remove the path in the column names from a text file in linux?

Tags: text-processing, awk, files

I have a tab-delimited text file `data.txt` that looks like the below:

```
# Program used for this                             
Geneid  Chr Start   End Strand  Length  /users/doc3/data/Q0062/input/HPR4/HPR4.bam  /users/doc3/data/Q0062/input/HPR5_ctrl/HPR5_ctrl.bam    /users/doc3/data/Q0062/input/HPR6/HPR6.bam
ENSG00000224571.1   GL000008.2  5072    5352    -   281 0   0   0
ENSG00000226369.1   GL000008.2  20450   20767   +   318 0   0   0
ENSG00000280961.1   GL000008.2  24985   25272   +   288 0   0   0
ENSG00000227871.1   GL000008.2  43499   43703   +   205 0   0   0
ENSG00000251917.1   GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2    83529;83927;84030;85457;85567;85567;85593;88636;88636;173516;173838 83545;84145;84145;85477;85625;85625;85625;88789;88789;173643;173931 +;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+   692 0   3   2
ENSG00000231423.1   GL000008.2  115523  115813  +   291 0   0   5
ENSG00000228465.1   GL000008.2  119026  119424  +   399 11  4   7
ENSG00000232585.1   GL000008.2  120703  120999  +   297 5   0   0
ENSG00000234081.1   GL000008.2;GL000008.2   124725;153003   124857;153715   +;+ 846 2   1   0
ENSG00000172352.5   GL000008.2  130736  131045  +   310 4   2   1
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
# Program used for this                             
Geneid  Chr Start   End Strand  Length  HPR4    HPR5_ctrl   HPR6
ENSG00000224571.1   GL000008.2  5072    5352    -   281 0   0   0
ENSG00000226369.1   GL000008.2  20450   20767   +   318 0   0   0
ENSG00000280961.1   GL000008.2  24985   25272   +   288 0   0   0
ENSG00000227871.1   GL000008.2  43499   43703   +   205 0   0   0
ENSG00000251917.1   GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2    83529;83927;84030;85457;85567;85567;85593;88636;88636;173516;173838 83545;84145;84145;85477;85625;85625;85625;88789;88789;173643;173931 +;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+   692 0   3   2
ENSG00000231423.1   GL000008.2  115523  115813  +   291 0   0   5
ENSG00000228465.1   GL000008.2  119026  119424  +   399 11  4   7
ENSG00000232585.1   GL000008.2  120703  120999  +   297 5   0   0
ENSG00000234081.1   GL000008.2;GL000008.2   124725;153003   124857;153715   +;+ 846 2   1   0
ENSG00000172352.5   GL000008.2  130736  131045  +   310 4   2   1
```

So, if you look from the 7th column instead of the whole path I just want to show the name before the last `/`. For my original file I have 100 columns with different names

Instead of creating a new file, I want to make changes to the same `data.txt` file. How to do this?

Comment: Will the changes be only in the first line (header)? Or do you have more rows with paths?

Comment: And what columns do have `paths`? from `6th` column to the last column?

Comment: And do all your paths contain `.bam` at the end of this one?

Comment: Similar to the question posed by @EdgarMagallon, does each file contain a single record? Or are their multiple records per file (each record with a header you'd like altered)?

Comment: Regarding `Instead of creating a new file, I want to make changes to the same data.txt file.` - do you REALLY need that? Because sed, perl, ruby, awk, python, etc. don't do that with their "inplace editing" options and so then you'd need to create a copy of the input file first which can be more error-prone than redirecting output or use `ed` or to manually create a buffer inside one of the other tools to write to the input file after reading and then closing it which is all very convoluted vs simply using a temp file (internally or externally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using any awk, here's how to manipulate the text as shown in your example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==2{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { sub("/[^/]*$","",$i); sub(".*/","",$i) } } 1' file
# Program used for this
Geneid  Chr     Start   End     Strand          HPR4    HPR5_ctrl       HPR6
ENSG00000224571.1       GL000008.2      5072    5352    -       281     0       0       0
ENSG00000226369.1       GL000008.2      20450   20767   +       318     0       0       0
ENSG00000280961.1       GL000008.2      24985   25272   +       288     0       0       0
ENSG00000227871.1       GL000008.2      43499   43703   +       205     0       0       0
ENSG00000251917.1       GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2        83529;83927;84030;85457;85567;85567;85593;88636;88636;173516;173838     83545;84145;84145;85477;85625;85625;85625;88789;88789;173643;173931     +;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+   692     0       3       2
ENSG00000231423.1       GL000008.2      115523  115813  +       291     0       0       5
ENSG00000228465.1       GL000008.2      119026  119424  +       399     11      4       7
ENSG00000232585.1       GL000008.2      120703  120999  +       297     5       0       0
ENSG00000234081.1       GL000008.2;GL000008.2   124725;153003   124857;153715   +;+     846     2       1       0
ENSG00000172352.5       GL000008.2      130736  131045  +       310     4       2       1
```

or, if you prefer:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==2{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ( (n=split($i,a,"/")) > 1 ) $i=a[n-1] } 1' file
# Program used for this
Geneid  Chr     Start   End     Strand          HPR4    HPR5_ctrl       HPR6
ENSG00000224571.1       GL000008.2      5072    5352    -       281     0       0       0
ENSG00000226369.1       GL000008.2      20450   20767   +       318     0       0       0
ENSG00000280961.1       GL000008.2      24985   25272   +       288     0       0       0
ENSG00000227871.1       GL000008.2      43499   43703   +       205     0       0       0
ENSG00000251917.1       GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2;GL000008.2        83529;83927;84030;85457;85567;85567;85593;88636;88636;173516;173838     83545;84145;84145;85477;85625;85625;85625;88789;88789;173643;173931     +;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+;+   692     0       3       2
ENSG00000231423.1       GL000008.2      115523  115813  +       291     0       0       5
ENSG00000228465.1       GL000008.2      119026  119424  +       399     11      4       7
ENSG00000232585.1       GL000008.2      120703  120999  +       297     5       0       0
ENSG00000234081.1       GL000008.2;GL000008.2   124725;153003   124857;153715   +;+     846     2       1       0
ENSG00000172352.5       GL000008.2      130736  131045  +       310     4       2       1
```

As for ending up with the same input file name containing the output, just google it, there's a million answers all saying the same, trivial things that aren't worth regurgitating in every answer on this or any other forum now.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
sed -Ei "s|/\S*/([^/]*)\.bam|\1|g" data.txt
```

- Look for a string which starts with `/`
- Any number of non-space symbols
- Another `/`
- A group of not `/`
- Ends with `.bam`

if such string is found - replace it with a first group.

Repeat until no such strings would be found.

Comment: you should add `''` before `"s|/\S*/([^/]*)\.bam|\1|g"`. But still it didn't give the desired output.

Comment: That do you expect the empty string to do? Try again without adding anything.

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for `\S` and that syntax of `-i`.